# Custom database update through DataGridView using a DataAdapter

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

My DataGridView control is DataSource-bound to a TableAdapter.

The table holds sales per day:

```
Date         Sales
12/03/2012   100
12/04/2012   50
12/06/2012   120
```

I want the DataGrid to display also the days when no sale was made with an empty cell:

```
Date         Sales
12/03/2012   100
12/04/2012   50
12/05/2012   
12/06/2012   120
```

If I change the emtpy cell (zero sales) in the grid view I want this to be written to the table as new row, otherwise it should not be written to the table. DB is a local Access file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest handling conversion manually in this case, For example, create a proxy class between your DataAdapter and DataGridView, so they will not be directly connected. This way DataAdapter will save to database for you, and you just do the conversion.

**EDIT:** Here are some ideas to get you started. Below code will create a dummy table, which you can use for testing purposes - it does not depend on DataAdapter at all:

```vb
Dim originalDataTable As New DataTable
With originalDataTable.Columns
  .Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
  .Add("Sales", GetType(Integer))
End With
With originalDataTable.Rows
  .Add({#12/3/2012#, 100})
  .Add({#12/4/2012#, 50})
  .Add({#12/6/2012#, 120})
End With
```

Now prepare necessary structures, you will need this dictionary, so better declare a class level variable - probably a form in your case:

```vb
Dim salesDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Date, DataRow)
For Each row As DataRow In originalDataTable.Rows
  salesDictionary.Add(row("Date"), row)
Next

Dim minDate As DateTime = salesDictionary.Keys.Min
Dim maxDate As DateTime = salesDictionary.Keys.Max
Dim newTable As DataTable = originalDataTable.Clone
Dim currentDate As DateTime = minDate
Do
  Dim row As DataRow = Nothing
  If salesDictionary.TryGetValue(currentDate, row) Then
    newTable.ImportRow(row)
  Else
    newTable.Rows.Add({currentDate, Convert.DBNull})
  End If
  currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
Loop While currentDate <= maxDate
```

Bind your DataGridView to `newTable` instead of `originalDataTable`, and when ready to commit your changes, manually update relevant records in `originalDataTable` like this:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In newTable.Rows
  Dim newSalesValue As Object = row("Sales")
  Dim originalRow As DataRow = Nothing
  If salesDictionary.TryGetValue(row("Date"), originalRow) Then
    If newSalesValue Is Convert.DBNull Then
      originalRow.Delete()
    Else
      originalRow("Sales") = row("Sales")
    End If
  ElseIf newSalesValue IsNot Convert.DBNull Then
    originalDataTable.ImportRow(row)
  End If
Next
```

Then use your DataAdapter to update the database.

Comment: So you suggest I remove the sourcebinding of the grid control and load the tableadapter query into a new dataset, do the changes and then bind the new dataset as source to the grid control? Could you give a quick code example for this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use the OnRowDataBound and manipulate the data when its applied row by row.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would treat the data retrieval and storage differantly in this instance.

For the Select statement, I would suggest you build a permenat table with say 10000 rows with 2 columns, one of integers from 1 to 10000, and one of dates from a day far enough in the past to be usefull (1/1/1900? 1/1/2000?) and going up to 10000 days later.

You can then use a view (query) left join from this table to your table on the date column with appropriate start and stop dates, this leverages the best attributes orf RDMS - data retrieval and matching. Unfortunately this query will not be updatable.

Going back the other way, for rows that were already populated you need to update them, but for rows that were nulls you need to insert them.

I will warn you that I have not tried this and I'm not sure that access can handle it, but ... If you set the Update property of your dbdataadaptor to run an insert (for the originally null rows) and an update (for the originally populated rows) in that order then you should be sweet.

**Update** It seems I was wrong - the query is updateable directly in access - if you write the following query

```
SELECT     IndexTable.dateIndex, Sales.Sales
FROM       IndexTable
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Sales ON IndexTable.dateIndex = Sales.SaleDate)
WHERE      (IndexTable.dateIndex >=
                      (SELECT     MIN(SaleDate) AS Expr1
                        FROM          Sales Sales_2)) AND 
           (IndexTable.dateIndex <=
                      (SELECT     MAX(SaleDate) AS Expr1
                        FROM          Sales Sales_1))
```

and bind this, any changes you make should flow back to the table.